# Family of continuous bounded functions has uniformly convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, arzela-ascoli

Let $\{f_n\} \subset C(-2,2)$ with $||f_n||_{L^\infty(-2,2)}\leq 1$. Assume for any $x,y\in (-1,1)$, there holds $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\leq |x-y|^\alpha $ for some $\alpha\in (0,1)$ whenever $|x-y|>\frac{1}{3n}$. Then show that there exist $f\in C(-1,1)$ such that subsequence of $f_n$ converges unifomly to $f$ on $(-1,1)$ or give counterexapmle.

My attempt: I was trying to apply **Arzela-Ascoli** theorem. To show the uniformly equicontinuous I do not know how to control when $|x-y|<\frac{1}{3n}$. Also, I am not sure about the conterexample that such convergence can not happen.

Any help/hint in this regards would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by counterexample? Do you mean if the statement is not true?

Comment: The role of $\alpha$ is also not clear from the formulation. Is $\alpha$ a fixed, given number, or do you only know that for given $n$ such an $\alpha$ exists? If I take your formulation serios it's the latter.

Comment: @Thomas The $\alpha$ is fixed and independent on $n$.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Counterexample means such statement might not be true. Then such sequence exists with all the hypothesis true but it has no convergent subsequence.

Comment: @RipCheck So you're not sure the statement is true. That was essentially what I was asking, or whether this is an exercise from some book.